# retrieving coordinates from firebase and draw it on map

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored a set of coordinates in Firebase and I want to bring these coordinates to my Android project and set them on a map as markers and draw straight lines between them.
So this is my onMapReady code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(34.505688, 36.5946491);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 16));
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();}
```

And in MyAsycTask have this code:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        gettingCoordinates();

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        drawPath();
    }
}
```

The two methods used in MyAsycTask is there:

```
    public void gettingCoordinates(){
    fireget.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            HashMap<String,String> value=new HashMap<>();
            value=(HashMap<String,String>)dataSnapshot.getValue();

            Lan=Double.parseDouble(value.get("Latitude"));
            Long=Double.parseDouble(value.get("Longitude"));



            points.add(i,new LatLng(Lan,Long));

            i++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

And there:

```
    public void drawPath(){
    for (LatLng point : points) {

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker))
                .anchor(0.2f, 1.0f)
                .position(point));

        PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                .width(5)
                .color(Color.RED)
                .add(point);
        polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
        polyline.setPoints(points);
    }
}
```

**So my question is: when I run the code it execute the drawPath method in the first then go to execute the gettingCoordinates method** 
There is my firebase structure:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CbYY.png
I hope that you can help me.

Comment: And what is happening when you are using this code?

Comment: it is just open the application with map with out drawing @AlexMamo